# Parse Promises. Accessing variables across Promises

Tags: parse-platform

Parse Promises.  I"m new to using Promises.  Fairly simple example below.  So, the results I get from one Promise, I don't know how to pass it to the next Promise.  Ideas greatly appreciated!  I've tried a couple of ideas.  Nothing works except the last "hard coded" one.

```
}).then(function(results) {

      var BsellerObjectId = results.id;  
      alert ("WHOO-HOO!  Saved" + BsellerObjectId);

}).then(function(valedictorian) {

      var BumpSold = Parse.Object.extend("BumpSold");
      var BumpSold = new BumpSold();
      BumpSold.id = "QmJNz4x2EC";                                      

  return BumpSold.save({ BsellerObjectId: BsellerObjectId});        // doesn't work
  return BumpSold.save({ BsellerObjectId: results.id});             // doesn't work
  return BumpSold.save({ BsellerObjectId: "Hello"});                // WORKS!
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you're using custom Promises, you can pass the result of a Promise to another through the success callback of a promise result.

```
extends.foo = function(){

    var promise = new Parse.Promise();

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("name","Joe");
    query.find().then(function(results) {        

      if (results.length > 0)
        promise.resolve(results[0]);
      else
        promise.reject(-2);

    }, function(error) {
        promise.reject(-1);
    });

    return promise;
}


extends.foo2 = function(){

    var promise = new Parse.Promise();

    this.foo().then(function(result){

      // success case
      promise.resolve({uselessParam:123,firstResult:result})


    },function(error){

      // error case
      promise.reject(error); // so, -1 or -2 returned by the promise in foo()

    });
    return promise;
}


// usage

extends.foo3 = function(){

    this.foo2().then(function(result){

      console.log(result.uselessParam); // added in the foo2()
      console.log(result.firstResult); // returned by the foo() and added again in the foo2() 

    },function(error){

      console.log(error); // so, -1 or -2 returned by the promise in foo()

    });
}
```

You can also define a variable in the main function into which you are using the promises (but out from them) an so set it promise by promise

Hope it helps!

Comment: Luca:  Thanks for this.  I'm having trouble following your code.  What  is being passed to the next Promise?

Comment: the trick is to pass a value "hello" in the promise "1" in his promise.resolve  method ( that means the value you will be able to read in the success callback, when you'll use it ). I've created some function that return  promise as function result. As you make for a query in a query.find().then(...) the "then()" method has the "success callback" as first params and "error callback" as second params. Into his success callback,that is written for example as "function(result){..}" you can retrieve the passed hello value from the result, at which you had previously assigned with promise.resolve